# KDE clipboard - dictionary integration

Tags: kde, clipboard

I'd like to know if there is a way to integrate a dictionary with KDE's clipboard tool (Klipper).

I noticed that you can "Enable clipboard actions" which allows it to do stuff like detect URL's and offer to open them in a browser. Is there a way to add an action for a dictionary look-up?

I guess one solution would be to define my own trigger and command, but I want to know if there is a more streamlined way to achieve this.